# Breezejs nested Array and results bindings

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

Using breezejs and WEBAPI, I pulling a list of Products each product has a list of components.

> ```
>     var list = function (productsObservable) {
>         var query = EntityQuery.from('Products')
>                     .expand('components')
>         return manager.executeQuery(query)
>                 .then(querySucceeded)
>                 .fail(datacontext.queryFailed);
>
>         function querySucceeded(data) {
>             // process results
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
> function querySucceeded(data) {
>     productsObservable(data.results);
> }
>
>     var productsObservable= ko.observableArray([]);
> ```

The raw results show a list of 3 components for a the first product in the list, while when i navigate data.results[0].component() i get only one component in the array.

Same thing when i browse to /breeze/Breeze/products, i see all the components for each product.

Am Missing anything ? Here's the response that i get when i call /breeze/Breeze/products directly.

```
 {
    $id: "1",
    $type: "DD.Product, DD_Model",
    Id: 1,
    Name: "XXXX",
    Components: [
    {
        $id: "2",
        $type: "DD.Component, DD_Model",
        Id: 1,
        Name: "component1"
        Product: {
           $ref: "1"
         },
    },
    {
        $id: "3",
        $type: "DD.Component, DD_Model",
        Id: 2,
        Name: "component2"
        Product: {
          $ref: "1"
        },
    },
    {
        $id: "4",
        $type: "DD.Component, DD_Model",
        Id: 11,
        Name: "component3"
        Product: {
         $ref: "1"
        },
    }
    ],
  },
```

Objects meta-data is retrieved from the server through /breeze/Breeze/metadata

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using two separate data types and putting them into the components array.

I have a feeling that when you get the JSON back it has those additional properties but they aren't going to be mapped to DD.Components because they are of type GCDMS.Models.CalibrationEquipment, GCDMS_Model.

**EDIT**

For all intents and purposes what you are doing looks correct, provided that what you are showing matches the data returned, etc...

The only thing that I can suggest is that after your results are returned, put this in a method and call it - console.log(entityManager.getEntities()); and see if there are 3 components and make sure they are mapped back properly.

Comment: That was only a copy&paste mistake, fixed it, Structure-wise all the components are the same, nothing different.

Comment: Show your querySucceeded function then please.  Also are you using server meta data or setting up your own?

Comment: Added querySucceed function and yes i'm pulling metadata from the server. Thx.

Comment: Updated the answer, but there are no obvious problems shown.  Are you sure the model on the server is set up correctly?  Seems like a long shot...